# DateTime Parse Based on Search Function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a search function which includes dates also. The problem that i have is this:

when you add 2 dates in the search function for example:

2013-04-10 and 2013-04-11 it displays just for 2013-04-10 until 23:59 or if i search the same date

2013-04-10 and 2013-04-10 it doesn't find any hit.

the code is this:

```
Func<string, string> emptyToNull = s => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? null : s.Trim();

var from = emptyToNull(input.CreditApplicationSearchFromDate);
var to = emptyToNull(input.CreditApplicationSearchToDate);

from = from ?? DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
to = to ?? DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

And i was thinking to do like this:

```
Func<string, string> emptyToNull = s => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? null : s.Trim();

var from = emptyToNull(input.CreditApplicationSearchFromDate);
var to = emptyToNull(input.CreditApplicationSearchToDate);

from = from ?? new DateTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
to = to ?? new DateTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

but is not good and i don't know how to do to display when i search for example
2013-04-10 and 2013-04-10 to find the hits for all day

Comment: How are the `from` and `to` strings used for search?

Comment: Just a head-up. I wouldn't use keyword reserved words as identifiers. In your case "from"

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the start and end hours of the whole day, or better yet - the very start of the next day:

```
from = from ?? DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
to = to ?? new DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Note the use of `Now.Date` giving you the current date without a time component (`new DateTime()` will not compile, so I don't really know where you got that piece of code from).

Comment: Indeed, a very common mistake. If you enter a date with no time it defaults to midnight. People usually don't think about it, or interpret midnight whichever way is more convenient in the circumstance.

Comment: Oded can you give me an example so i can guide my self through?

Comment: If you were being pedantic and wanted the 'to' date to be the very end of the day, rather than the very start of the day after, you could add 1 day then subtract 1 tick, e.g. **`var toDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);`** The time component of this date will be in the format of **23:59.59.9999999**